# Grails app not allowing value modifications despite scaffolding

Tags: java, database, oracle, grails, grails-orm

I've created a simple Grails app connecting to a table in an Oracle 12 database which is supposed to provide a CRUD for data there. So I have a simple model class like this:

```
package moduleprototype

class ConfigTest {
    int configid
    String name
    String type
    String value
    String description
    int status

    static constraints = {
        version false
        id column: 'CONFIGID', name:'configid',  type: 'integer'
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
package moduleprototype

class ConfigTestController {

    static scaffold = ConfigTest
}
```

But when I navigate to the controller in my browser, while all the data from the `config_test` table is displayed properly, it's all plain text in a table, not clickable links for every value which would allow you to change them (which they [should be](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) according to the official guide). Why is that?

The scaffolding is on in the controller so it should theoretically work, and from what I remember from the tutorial app, that was enough for it to automatically allow in-browser modification interface so I'm guessing the reason here is that I'm using an external database instead of the built-in one? How can I fix this so that all the values are again clickable, modifiable and deletable?

EDIT: So to better illustrate my problem, here's an example of scaffolding from the tutorial app where in every row, every value is a link to the `/show/` page where a given value can be modified or deleted (which is what I'm trying to achieve):

[image]

While in my case, everything (weirdly, apart from the first column, which is my id) is just plain text. The values in the configid column, though, are links, but all just pointing to itself (i.e. `/ConfigTest/index`).

Comment: Not sure every field should be clickable from the list view, you should have one clickable link though which'll take you to the show view from which you can navigate to edit IIRC?

Comment: @MikeW - I added a screenshot of what I meant - in the tutorial app, simple scaffolding made the app add hyperlinks to every value, pointing them to their corresponding `/show/` view while here, they're all (apart from the ID column) plain text.

Comment: I think the reason the links in the image shown are links is that they are separate domains, your model is made up of strings and ints so you edit all this on your domain edit page

Comment: @MikeW - nope, in the example here, `Make` is a domain but `Name` is a simple string parameter and yet it's clickable :(

Comment: Name is the link to edit the domain you're currently looking at, Make is a link to the Make domain

Comment: @MikeW - hm, so why don't I have any link to edit the domain I'm currently looking at in the case mentioned in the post to edit the value, description, status etc.? It's the same scenario and yet the values aren't links here (it's obvious why they aren't links to the other domain, but they aren't links to the same domain editing either, while in the tutorial app they were).

Comment: I doubt the scaffolding implementation can handle your domain constraints configuration. It might require a field called id and/or a version. Might worth to play with those settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaffolding mechanism needs to find a field named `id` to work.

Just change your domain class to

```
package moduleprototype

class ConfigTest {
    int id //int configid
    String name
    String type
    String value
    String description
    int status

    static mapping /*constraints*/ = {
        version false
        id column: 'CONFIGID', name:'id' /*name:'configid'*/,  type: 'integer'
    }
}
```

At least that fixed that error for me with a small test with grails 3.3

Comment: That's exactly that! Thanks so much, fixed my problem in an instant :)